# return string array of cloudfiles in directory azure file storage c#

Tags: c#, arrays, azure, file-storage

```
  public IEnumerable<IListFileItem> GetFilesInDirectory()
    {
        var directory = GetFileShareDirectory();
        IEnumerable<IListFileItem> allFilesInDirectory = directory.ListFilesAndDirectories();
        List<IListFileItem> allFiles = new List<IListFileItem>();

        foreach (var file in allFilesInDirectory)
        {
            string[] fileType = file.GetType().ToString().Split('.');
            string type = fileType[fileType.Length - 1];
            if (type == "CloudFile")
            {
                allFiles.Add(file);
            }
        }
        return allFiles;
    }
```

This code returns all the files in the directory on fileshare on azure, is there any way I can change this to an array? The method I am trying to us wants an array. Please advice, Thank you

Comment: Did you try `allFiles.ToArray()`?

Comment: cast Ienumerable to Array before returning return allFiles.ToArray(); will this help you ?

Comment: no these does not help

Comment: And why not? At least explain what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way I can change this to an array?

If you want to get an array when call this method, you also need to change the return type to **IListFileItem[]** in addition to add ToArray method.

```
public IListFileItem[] GetFilesInDirectory()
{
    var directory = GetFileShareDirectory();
    IEnumerable<IListFileItem> allFilesInDirectory = directory.ListFilesAndDirectories();
    List<IListFileItem> allFiles = new List<IListFileItem>();

    foreach (var file in allFilesInDirectory)
    {
        string[] fileType = file.GetType().ToString().Split('.');
        string type = fileType[fileType.Length - 1];
        if (type == "CloudFile")
        {
            allFiles.Add(file);
        }
    }
    return allFiles.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Any updates? Have you tried my suggestions? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.